# What do you call different user roles in software design?

Tags: programming-practices, naming, users

I'm just curious, I'm building a web app with a User model which has role-based permissions.

I have the following roles:

- Visitor (anonymous user)
- ?? (logged-in user)
- Moderator
- Admin

I'm having a hard time figuring out what to call a logged-in user. I want to just call them "users", but I find that having a role with the same name as the class creates confusing code sometimes. For instance: `if user.user? then...`

If you've built software with roles for users, what do you call the basic, registered, no special permissions, user role?

*EDIT:* As a side consideration, this app has Subscribers and Non Subscribers. Whether or not a user is a subscriber is not the same as their role, but it affects the way I've been thinking about this. For instance, calling a regular user a "member" sounds a lot like what I would call a subscriber, so I haven't been too fond of that. I haven't ruled it out though.

Comment: Hero, villain, comic relief...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All the following are conceptually opposite of **Anonymous**, I address your use of the name **Visitor** as related to the definition of **Anonymous** below.

**Authenticated User** - your use of *logged in* in implies supplying some sort of credentials.

**Identified User** - implies you know who there are based on the login information.

**Verified User** - implies some checking of credentials and known information.

**Known User** - a direct Antonym of **Anonymous**.

Other possibilities are the opposite of **Anonymous**, the [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.com/) is a good place to start looking for names, they usually provide great semantically more relevant synonyms, but also a good choice of antonyms.

Also it is implied that **Moderator** and **Admin** are logged in, and technically sub-roles of your logged in state user.

**NOTE:** The [Antonym](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20synonym) of **Visitor** is **Host**.

The definition of **Visitor** is *person temporarily in a foreign location*, it doesn't imply that they are **Anonymous** which is *unknown, usually by choice*

So it isn't semantically a [Synonym](http://www.google.com/search?q=define%20synonym) for **Anonymous** user.

[english.stackexchanged.com](https://english.stackexchange.com/) is a good place to ask this type of advice as well.

Comment: I think "authenticated" is pretty much exactly the meaning I'm thinking of. Thanks for the many suggestions!

Answer (score 5):

**Member** (logged-in user).

Maybe you have already considered and discarded this. In that case i would like to think some more. But maybe it was so obvious you overlooked it.

Comment: This crossed my mind, and I'd say it's my fallback position. I added a note to the question to clarify -- to me member implies subscriber, and in this app whether a user is a subscriber or not does not affect their role.

Comment: Please add "EDIT:" to the change in your question, otherwise someone might think i didnt't read your question :-)

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Registered User**

To indicate that the user is registered with the system. I.E. the system knows information about the user and allows him/her to sign in.

Comment: I don't see why the downvote. Maybe it's not the best option but it's not worth the downvote IMHO.

Comment: Yes, downvote with no feedback, best way for me to know why is it wrong, how to improve it, or why I should remove it.

Comment: ...or Registrant

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the names matter all the much, as long as they make sense.

The application I work on we have:

```
Users
Policies
Roles
```

Roles are grouping of policies.

Policies could be:

```
Access Admin Console
Run Reports
Import Content
etc.
```

When a user logs in and authenticates, we check what role they have been assigned to and that is there role.

We have canned roles built in for certain policy groupings, but most of the time cutomers build thier own.  We have one special role called Super Admin which can't be removed, but the rest they can group and name however they see fit.

Answer (score -3):

For something like this I would probably use **Customer**.

It is less offensive that the term user(has a connotation of someone who uses with nothing in return). The creation of a login is much like coming into a storefront to shop. Perhaps the customer buys something perhapas they dont. They are still your customer and you treat them as if they were buying.

Comment: -1. This term is the least appropriate in this context. If by customer, you mean somebody who actually paid you, it's actually the subscriber. If by customer, you mean somebody who uses the service, an anonymous user uses it too. So in both cases, the term customer is confusing and not appropriate.

Comment: Actually businesses have customers who buy nothing all the time. I have customers people who recieve from me that pay me nothing.